# VBA Confirm Sheet Existence

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, count

I'm trying to verify that a sheet exists in my workbook. It will confirm if the sheet name in the workbook exists in my array. If it does not exist then a new worksheet will be added and renamed based on the array. If it does exist, I want the code to continue with checking the next worksheet name.

This is what I have so far but my last array value "Test 7" won't pop up in my new worksheets added. It will only show "Test7" as the new name. Please help!

```
Dim SheetNames() As Variant
SheetNames()= Array("Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4","Test5","Test6","Test7")
For n =LBound(SheetNames) To UBound(SheetNames)
On Error Resume Next
   If Not Worksheets(SheetNames(n)).Name=SheetNames(n) Then
        Set cws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=ws)
   End If
   Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cancel the `On Error Resume Next` as soon as you no longer need it, or you may be hiding unexpected problems in the rest of your code.

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim SheetNames() As Variant, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, n As Long
    
    SheetNames() = Array("Test1", "Test2", "Test3", _
                   "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7")
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'for example
    
    For n = LBound(SheetNames) To UBound(SheetNames)
        Set ws = Nothing                       'reset ws to Nothing
        On Error Resume Next                   'ignore errors
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(SheetNames(n))  'try to set `ws`
        On Error GoTo 0                        'stop ignoring errors
        If ws Is Nothing Then                  'got a sheet?
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
            ws.Name = SheetNames(n)
        End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Add Missing Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddMissingWorksheets()
    
    Dim SheetNames(): SheetNames = Array( _
        "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sh As Object, SheetName
    
    For Each SheetName In SheetNames
        On Error Resume Next
            Set sh = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sh Is Nothing Then ' sheet doesn't exist
            wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Name = SheetName
        Else ' sheet exists
            Set sh = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        End If
    Next SheetName

    MsgBox "Missing worksheets added.", vbInformation

End Sub
```